# XSLT stylesheet to select specific child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and am trying to transform an xml:

```
`<xml>
    <id1>1</id1>
    <id2>2</id2>
    <abc>
        <a>a</a>
        <b>b</b>
        <c>c</c>
    </abc>
</xml>`
```

to another xml:

```
`<xml>
    <id1>1</id1>
    <abc>
        <a>a</a>
        <b>b</b>
    </abc>
 </xml>`
```

What stylesheet can I use to achieve this?

The rules for transformation:
id1, abc/a and abc/b elements are to be retained. All other elements are to be ignored, that is, I have a specific set of elements that I wish to retain while ignoring all others.

Comment: An example is not enough; please explain the **rules** for the transformation.

Comment: @ michael.hor257k. thanks added the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a "white" list of nodes to keep, then the simplest way to implement it would be by using it to apply templates selectively:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="id1 | abc"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a | b"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="id1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="abc"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="a | b"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```